# Scroll where click occurred - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my jQuery code:

```
 $(document).on("click", '.sidebarExternalLink', function (e) {
            if($(this).data("leftmenu")){
                $('#sidebar .list a[href*="'+ $(this).data("leftmenu") +'"]').click();
            }else{
                $('#sidebar .list a[href*="'+ $(this).attr("href").split('?')[0] +'"]').click();
            }
        });
```

What this code does is when I click on a document link on main page it redirects to documents list page and clicks corresponding document and shows details. The problem is that now it's just redirecting to the page and then I have to scroll and look which document is opened. What I want to do is to scroll down automatically to the opened document. Any suggestion how to do that? If you have any questions I am happy to answer.

Here is the code on document list page:

```
$('.js-toggle-table-details').on('click', function() {
                var $tablerow = $(this).next('.table-row-details');
                $('.table-row-details').not($tablerow).hide();
                $($tablerow).slideToggle("slow");
            });
```

Comment: you should give some ID to the `div` where document is opened and append that in the `href` like `a[href*="'+ $(this).data("leftmenu") +'#divid"]`

Comment: You can set focus to particular link. So it will automatically scroll down.

Comment: @Urvi can you show how to do that?

Comment: @ebilgin I am checking it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On document ready event I filtered the elements with css property and scrolled to opened one. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
           var toggledItem = $('.table-row-details').filter(function() {
                return $(this).css('display') == 'table-row';
            });
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: toggledItem.offset().top
            }, 500);
        })
```

If you have better solution please post it.

Comment: It's a good-enough solution, but I'd rather appending a "selected" class to filter the element(s) you want to focus, instead of relying on a css property. You can use .addClass() method to do it.